# Unable to connect to Wifi plus something really weird

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I did something weird with aptitude again (gotta stop messing with that). It appears that I maybe uninstalled the driver for my wireless network adapter (it doesn't show up when I run `ifconfig` and it is labeled `UNCLAIMED` when I run `lshw -class network`), so I cannot connect to any wireless networks, of course. However I cant connect to the internet over ethernet, either. Or more accurately, I can't connect to the majority of the internet.

With a wired connection, if I try to ping 8.8.8.8 I get `Destination Host Unreachable` thrown back at me. If I jump into a web browser I can access google and all of it's services and I can perform web searches. However I cannot visit any other websites.

Most frustratingly, I cannot look for updates or reinstall the wireless device drivers.

Here is the output of `ifconfig` for the machine in question:

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:26:0a:85:ef:34  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e2e00000-e2e20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:57321 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57321 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:5105529 (5.1 MB)  TX bytes:5105529 (5.1 MB)
```

and output for `lshw -class network`:

```
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 19
     bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
     logical name: eno1
     version: 04
     serial: 5c:26:0a:85:ef:34
     size: 1Gbit/s
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=169.229.192.85 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
     resources: irq:26 memory:e2e00000-e2e1ffff memory:e2e80000-e2e80fff ioport:4080(size=32)

*-network UNCLAIMED
     description: Network controller
     product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
     version: 34
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:e2d00000-e2d01fff
```

Comment: Sounds like a routing problem. What does `ip route` say? Is there a `default` route?

Comment: @waltinator Unclaimed hardware is not a routing problem.

Comment: Does wifi work after `sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi` and you could try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)` if it says iwlwifi not found

Comment: I solved one problem and am now able to connect to the wider internet as well as run system update. However, the wireless network adapter still returns `UNCLAIMED` and there appears to be no driver installed.

When I run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)` I get a few warnings that firmware for my chip set are missing but the command does not install them.